# What is the lifespan of a private variable in an GAE Endpoint class?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, variables, google-cloud-endpoints

I have the following code for an instant messenger style app.

```
public class MyEndpoint {
private Integer numberOfConvos=0;
...}
```

then I update it like this:

```
@ApiMethod (name="createGroup")
public myModel createGroup(@Named("profile") String profile){
    numberOfConvos=numberOfConvos+1;
}
```

So everytime I make a new chat, I can make a unique and increasing ID.

If I redeploy the backend (bug fix for example) would the variable be reset? I do not want to store this one token in the datastore, because it doesnt seem needed and datastore charges for reads/writes.

If it would be reset each time I deploy, what is the correct way to keep track of this variable?

If is does not reset when I redeploy, how could i force it to reset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-`static` variable is initialized for each thread. Several threads can be running on the same App Engine instance and your Cloud Endpoint service can be running on several instances in parallel.

So let's say that given the current load, you Cloud Endpoint service is served through 3 instances I1, I2, I3. Let's also say that each instances run 5 threads. In that case you would have **15 different versions of `numberOfConvos`** with 15 different values.

Keep also in mind that instances can be turned on or off by Google at any time, in which case your service would be moved to a different instance. **This would reset the `numberOfConvos` variable**.

To put it more generally : your java code should be stateless, you should not store state between requests in a variable, even a `static` one.

You have two choices here :

- If you do not want/need to keep track of the number of convos on the server and just want a way to uniquely identify each convo, then use the `UUID` class to generate a unique id for each convo, with very low risk of collision. [The documentation is here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) but a typical code would be :

  ```
  UUID.randomUUID().toString()
  ```
- If you want to keep track of the number of convos, or persist the convo ids on the server, your only choice is to use a database such as App Engine's datastore to keep track of the variable.  If you're new to this subject, I suggest you [read a bit about transactions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions), otherwise you will not be able to manage the state correctly. Note that App Engine can generate ids automatically for you.

Comment: As mentioned in my post, I didnt want to keep it in the datastore due to the many reads/writes we would incur, as well as a 1 lockout globally when I read/write to that Entity. For a chat app, that's not really an acceptable thing. I could always generate a random ID, and check to see if that ID has been made before (i do this in another place) however I'm not happy with the CPU overhead. Any other options as you see it?

Comment: You may want to take a look at sharding counters if you change your mind and wanted to use datastore.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters

Comment: If the id format is not important to you, and you don't want to store data in the datastore, use UUID to generate a random id with strong guarantees that it will not already exist.

Comment: Please write UUID as an answer and I will select it.